# Can someone help me integrate this function?

Tags: calculus

Integral of $$\frac {2\sin(x)-3}{\sin^2(x)-3\sin x+2}$$ I've tried using partial fractions but unsure how to integrate the two functions, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use substitution, setting $\;t=\tan \dfrac x2, \enspace\mathrm d\mkern1mu  t=\frac12(1+t^2)\mathrm d\mkern1mu  x$. This results in integrating a rational function, which you perform decomposing into partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function is equal to

$$\frac{(\sin{x}-2) +( \sin{x}-1)}{(\sin{x}-2)(\sin{x}-1)}= \frac1{\sin{x}-1} + \frac1{\sin{x}-2} $$

These may be handled by subbing $x=\pi/2-y$ and using half-angle formulae.